How to give physics to a dress?
I'm mostly done with the rigging of my character, but right now I have stumbled on an issue of how to make dress to move with legs. My dress look like this.


Parts of the dress that touch the body have weight painting so that it moves appropriately with rest of the body, but the other part is not, and I don't want it to look goofy. Any advice how to make it behave like real dress when someone is walking?

You could use a cloth simulation?

Hello, this tutorial is pretty good imho: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbyfuW5Aocg

First, I would Duplicate Part of the Torso Mesh and Seperate it into it's own Object.
Create a Collection Called "Collision"
Make sure to Enable "Collision" in your Physics Prooperties

Then, do the Same thing for the Dress and Extrude the Faces to Make a Cage Around your Skirt. But this Time Create a Collection Called "Cloth"

For the Cloth Cage you're going to want to Select these Verticies and Assign a Vertex Group Called "Pin" then Parent the Cage to the hip bone
Then in the Physics Properties you're going to Add a Cloth Sim.
Under "Shape" assign Pin Group to"Pin" In Collisions enable Object Collisions and assign your "Collision" Collection

On your Dress Object, Add A Surface Deform Modifier and Bind it to the Cloth Cage

if you Follow these Steps your Skirt will be Looking Flow-y.
If for Some Reason your Mesh Starts Spazzing or if there's a Region where Cloth sim isn't Influencing, you may have to Mess with Weight Paint.
I hope This Helps.

I got lost on a step where I'm supposed to "Then, do the Same thing for the Dress and Extrude the Faces to Make a Cage Around your Skirt." how do I extrude it to make cage out of it? Better yet is it possible to make a call on discord or something if you would be willing to help that way?

Ah My bad, to make a Cage from the Skirt, you'll have to: 1. Select the Skirt 2. go to Edit Mode 3. Select the Faces That you want the Skirt to bend Like Cloth 4. Press P> Seperate By Selection 5. Exit Edit mode and Select the Seperated Object 6. use the Solidify Modifier  to Extrude faces from both Sides 7. apply Modifier

Just checking in to see if you made any Progress. Do you have an Email where I can Reach you?

No, i'm still struggling. If you want to reach me you can do so by using gmail (xxthedr0nxx@gmail.com) or discord (rickys).

Add a cloth simulation to the dress, and then, going down to Shape, activate the pin group of whatever bone the dress is parented to.Make sure to add a collision to whatever objects you want the dress to react with, or it will just pass through it.


